# Synchronize Video / Audio with different numbers of audio channels

Tags: premiere, sync

I have a main video recording and audio recordings from 2 phone-based lav mic's. One subject's lav recording has 2 audio channels and the other has 1. (The video also has 1 audio channel)

I can synchronize the 1-CH recording to my video, but trying this with the 2-CH recording says `could not synchronize one or more clips in the current selection because a match could not be found`.

How can I sync the 2-CH audio file to my video? I'd assume that there should be a feature to automatically synchronize based on the lowest common number of Channels. Thank you!